# characterization of Riemann integerability

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{f_n (x)\} $ is a sequence of real valued Riemann integrable functions which converge to a function $f (x) $ ,
Is $f (x) $ Riemann integrable function?

I say **no**, but i cannt give counter example

Comment: What type of convergence?

Comment: If the convergence is uniformly, it is correct. But the question not select the type of convergence.

Comment: Do you have a favorite function $f$ that is not Riemann integrable? If so, you may be able to construct a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions converging pointwise to $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence of all rationals in $[0,1]$. For each $n$, put $f_n(p_m) = 1$ for $m\leq n$, and $f_n(x)=0$ everywhere else on $[0,1]$. Each $f_n$ has a finite number of discontinuities, hence is Riemann-integrable. Their limit is not.